# Rails 4 + ActiveRecord: group_by on column from different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

I have these models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_votes
  has_many :cars
end
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :car_votess
end
class GameVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :car
end
```

If I want to display cars that a user voted for (and group the output by the day when the user voted cars):

```
@voted_cars = @user.car_votes.order('car_votes.created_at DESC').group_by { |r| r.created_at.to_date }
```

So on the output are all cars which a user voted grouped by days the user voted the games.

But I would like to group the output now according to `car_votes.created_at`, but according to `cars.created_at`. How to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In class Car you have "has_many :car_votess" is that just a typo here or in your original code? Also is there a CarVote class? I only see GameVote.

Comment: Sorry, that's just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your associations allow you to do this(try it on the rails console):

```
@c = CarVote.first
puts @c.car.created_at
```

and you get a return value rather than an error, then you can do:

```
@voted_cars = @user.car_votes.order('car_votes.created_at DESC').group_by { |r| r.car.created_at.to_date }
```

Comment: You should be able to traverse using any valid association.

Comment: That's weird - I've tried this approach before posting the question here on SO, but it didn't work back then... (maybe I modified the models). Anyway, thanks!